# Where to initialize RecyclerView adapter with LiveData

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

I have a 2-dimensional LiveData list.

My fragment has a button and a RecyclerView. The button opens a dialog, which contains the items of the **outer list**. When I select an item in the dialog, I would like to display the items of the selected **inner list** in the RecyclerView.

My problem is that I don't know where to initialize the adapter. Should I initialize the adapter inside the observer's `onChanged` listener, the button's `onClick` listener or outside of them?

**Relevant code:**

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentSessionsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(SessionsViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getSessions().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<SessionData>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<SessionData> sessions) {
            /* ... */
        }
    });

    // sessionSelect => button
    binding.sessionSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SessionsListDialog dialog = new SessionsListDialog();
            dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
            dialog.sessionSelectListener = new SessionsListDialog.SessionSelectListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSessionSelected(int sessionId) {
                    viewModel.setSessionId(sessionId);
                    /* ... */
                }
            };
        }
    });

    // the adapter gets the list via its constructor
    tasksAdapter = new TasksAdapter(viewModel.getSessions().getValue().get(viewModel.getSessionId()).getTasks());
    
    // sessionTasks => recyclerview
    binding.sessionTasks.setAdapter(tasksAdapter);
    binding.sessionTasks.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

Using this code, the `getValue` method returns `null`, because the list is not ready at this point. It is being fetched from a local file in the fragment's parent activity. I could pass an empty list to the constructor, but **I am not sure whether it would run earlier every time than the observer.**

If I move the adapter initialization into the `observe` method, `getValue` works fine, and the RecyclerView is populated with the items. However, every time I add a new inner list to the outer list in a separate dialog (not shown in this piece of code), the adapter is re-initialized. **Isn't it redundant?**

And the last question is how I should give a new list to the adapter inside the `onClick` listener. **Should I call the adapter's constructor every time I select a new inner list in the dialog?**

I would be glad if someone could answer these questions.